# How to store instances of a class without directly creating variables

Tags: python-3.x, class, instances

I need to pull words and lines from a text file and I need to store them as an instance of a class.  However, there are multiple words and lines in the text file, how do I automate the process?

Traditional way to create an instance of a class:

```
class Text():

  def __init__(self, Title, Sents):
    '''Initializes an instance''
    self.title = Title
    self.sents= Sents

x = Text("Title", "Sents")
```

But I want to use the data (ie Title and Sents) that I have stored and create instances of a class without having to assign 50 variables.

Comment: How is the text file structured?

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the lines and create/add instances of the class to a list. Assuming the text file has two words per line separated by a space that correspond to the arguments you want to use to pass in while instantiating the class, you could do the following:

```
texts = []
with open('example.txt', 'r') as t:
  for line in t:
    texts.add(Text(*line.strip().split()))
```